# Embedded Windows Media Player refuses to unload media

Tags: c#, wmp, axwindowsmediaplayer

I have the Window Media Player control (axWindowsMediaPlayer) embedded in a forms application to play mp3 files.

When I try to unload the media, hoping it will disable the play button and not allow further playing of the music it refuses to do so. The last played track remains loaded and can be played.

The code I've tried so far to no effect is:

```
mediaPlayerObj.newMedia("");
mediaPlayerObj.currentMedia = null;
mediaPlayerObj.URL = "";
mediaPlayerObj.URL = null;
mediaPlayerObj.close();
```

Surely I'm missing something here? Any help would be gratefully received!

Comment: Is it firing the [Error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562416%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [MediaError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562440%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event by any chance?

Comment: Hi Tass, it's certainly not firing the Error event as I hook into that, not sure about the MediaError event, I'll check that out.

Comment: Nope, no ErrorEvent nor MediaError event fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to resolve this now and the resolution was this:

```
mediaPlayerObj.currentPlaylist.clear();
```